# Proof signing chain of signature with BouncyCastle

Tags: java, cryptography, certificate, digital-signature, bouncycastle

I want to proof the `CMSSignedData` signature I made with BouncyCastle. I want to verify its signing chain. How do I do that?

I have a certificate list:

```
List<X509Certificate> certList = new ArrayList<X509Certificate>();
certList.add(0, subjectCert);
certList.add(1, interCert);
certList.add(2, caCert);
```

And a cert store:

```
Store<X509Certificate> certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);
```

How can I verify a `CMSSignedData` signing chain with the certificate list?

Comment: Do you already have an answer for this yourself?